# How can I overwrite a jpg list of files in gimp using the command line

Tags: command-line-interface, gimp

I would like to optimize a list of jpe?g files  that I have in my website which are taking a lot of space, so I have been using gimp to save more space.

What I've been doing is to open a file in GIMP using the GUI and then saving the file with `File -> overwrite {file}.jpg` , and then I choose the quality to be 60%, and noticed that I can save a lot of space by doing this. Since I have hundreds of images in my site, I was wondering if there is a way to do this process with a script. I have seen the [GIMP Batch option](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) but I don't know what command to use to do what I wanted to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: GIMP is not the best tool for automate tasks like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use [ImageMagick's `mogrify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) for this:

```
magick mogrify -quality 60 foobar.jpg
```

In practice you can re-encode several files in one shot, and besides quality, you can also ensure that you are using the maximum chroma subsampling:

```
magick mogrify -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -quality 60 *.jpg
```

(in older versions of IM, the command is a plain `mogrify ...`, the `magick` command has been added recently to avoid name clashes with other commands).

Comment: I think mogrify is only for resizing isn't that right?

Comment: `mogrify` won't replace `gimp` for interactive editing, but it can do many things: change format/compress, scale, rotate, crop.... If you need to do things to pictures in batch, IM is the first thing to look at.

Comment: I found GraphicsMagick, which is a fork of ImageMagick and it did a better job by compressing JPG files. In any case I will accept the answer. But I would advice you mention that in your comment to help people in the future. Thank you.

Comment: I'll mention it if you can show figures for both (and actual parameters used)